# Building a window application using bunch of python files

Tags: python, windows

I want to create a window application , which will use bunch of python files. I am new to this , so i dont know how to do it.Please tell me a way for it.

Project Tree: main.py,a.py,b.py,c.py

Now the when the application is clicked it should run main.py and then main.py is written to create a GUI which will have several buttons that will use other files a.py ,b.py ,c.py

Till now i have tried using Py2exe and pyinstaller but that seems to create a .exe file for a single .py file

Comment: What library do you want to use, You have those like tkinter, kivy.. but to name a few.

Comment: I have used quite a few libraries like pywinauto,pyscreenshot,tkinter etc

Comment: So what *exactly* is your problem?

Comment: See, when i myself run this main.py , it executes perfectly, does proper imports of other .py files on button clicks as per main.py . The problem is I want to have a window application (.exe) that is transferrable to other users and that application needs to execute main file automatically on click.That is , they can just install that application and it should work

Comment: If you are targeting just windows, then pyinstaller should work fine

Comment: Pyinstaller is just creating the exe file for main.py but it is not able to include other import files. Main.exe is basically a GUI which has buttons , on clicking those buttons , other files gets executed, i want those also to be included.

Comment: There is no question. Please read [ask].